# Параллельное выполнение одной и той же функции в Python3 asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, aiohttp

начал изучать asyncio  на примере телеграмм бота - парсера(aiogram + aiohttp)
имеются 2 функции, которые делают сам запрос на сайт с нужными параметрами, синхронная и аснхронная

```
def get_url_sync(link):
    r = reqests.get(link)
    return(r)


async def get_url_async(link):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(link) as r:
            r =await r.text()
            return(r)
```

Я делаю одновременно разные запросы с двух устройств с 2х разных аккаунтов и получаю:
При использовании синхронной функции один из пользователей не получает результат, пока не получит другой, то есть программа ждет завершения reqests.get()
А при асинхронном выполнении, запросы отправляются праллельно, но пользователи получают один и тот же результат, который выполниться первым, то есть сами запросы с двух устройств разные, а await session.get() возвращает двум пользователям одинаковый html

Вопрос: Как распараллелить выполнение асинхронного запроса и получать верный result для каждого из пользователей?

Comment: С кодом всё в порядке, ошибка где-то в другом месте.

Comment: Я пробовал запускать синхронную функцию с помощью ThreadPoolExecutor, и результат был тем же самым.
ощущение, что я не правильным образом делаю сам вызов асинхронной функции

Comment: Тем более проблема не в приведённом коде.