# При повторном вызове асинхронной функции перезаписывается переменная

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, python-3.8

При повторном вызове асинхронной функции, в которой в этот момент выполнялась ещё одна асинхронная функция, ожидающая результат,  перезаписывается переменная, которая будет использоваться и после функции ожидания результата.

```
async def f(time):
   await async.wait(time)
   await send(time)
```

Как сделать чтобы при повторном запуске или создавался новый контекст или как по другому решить проблему. Чтобы переменная time не менялась от начала до конца в асинхронной функции

Comment: какая переменная? time?

Comment: правда что ли меняется?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172176/Параллельное-выполнение-одной-и-той-же-функции-в-python3-asyncio

тот же самый вопрос